# How many times per turn can a thief steal?

Tags: munchkin

Assume I'm a level 1 Thief. Is there a limit to the number of times I attempt to steal something? Can I just attempt over and over again until I get the thing? Does it even have to be on my turn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no limit on attempts per turn, but you do have to discard a card to attempt it, so you can't just attempt forever. From [the FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/):

> Q. How often can a Thief steal?
>
> A. As long as he has cards to discard.
>
> Q. What happens to a Level 1 Thief who fails an attempt to steal? Does he die?
>
> A. Nothing happens to him. You can't go below Level 1. (Beware the Level 1 Thief – he literally has nothing to lose!)